# How do I portray my experience if my old workplace got bought out and they changed everything?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, management

I worked for my previous employer, a newspaper, for over 10 years.  During that time, I created their branding and style.  I was responsible for the layout and advertisement design among other things.  I even updated their website to a fresher, responsive design.

The company was bought out by new owners and I could only stay there a month before I had to leave due to mistreatment by the new owners.

Since then, they changed the website back to the old design before I refreshed it and the quality of the newspaper has dropped dramatically.

They have effectively reversed everything I'd accomplished in the 12 years I worked there.  How do I portray this to a future employer?

Comment: Did you keep any copies, screen shots, print copies, or the like from your work?

Comment: Have you tried the Wayback Machine to see if the previous versions are posted there?

Comment: You don't have offline copies?

Answer (score 8):

As with any job where you can't show artifacts directly (for example, somebody might have worked on something that's private or even classified), you *talk about what you did*.  In your resume and cover letter as appropriate, describe the work you did and how it improved your product.  If you can measure that, even better!  (For example, did you gather any website metrics?)

You cannot control what your former employer does after you leave.  If you get as far as talking with somebody at your prospective new company you can explain that they've since changed the site, but it's hard to say that on a resume without sounding negative.  If you can do it smoothly, you can try to write the description of your work in such a way that somebody looking at the current site would notice a discrepancy, but that's iffy.

The other thing you can do is to show your work.  *Never rely on an employer for the sole copy of work you want to demonstrate.*  In a lot of areas this means you're out of luck; if you developed proprietary software, for example, you might not have anything to show.  But you worked on a *web site*, something that was by definition public (or you wouldn't mind that they've since changed it).  Look for a copy of your work in the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/), and dump a copy for yourself that you can show in your portfolio.  In the future, save copies of published work as you go.

Answer (score 0):

With things like branding and style, you can show what you did and they may or may not like it. You're current employer didn't like it, so you can't always count on people having good taste.

What benefits were there to the company as a result of your work? Can you show any increases in revenue or any types of rewards your paper may have received at this time?

If your company had any kind of reputation in the industry during those years compared to now, you want to portray yourself as someone who helped make that happen.